# Left Outer Join and Null Value conversion

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I split my input data, with two selects with different where clauses, I then want to join them back together after some aggregation, with a left outer join.

This works fine, and the joined data from the left table have null values as expected. This would be okay if I could do a IsNull(lefttable.column,0), but IsNull is not supported as far as I can see, is there any alternative way to structure my statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "IS NULL" operator (same as in TSQL)

If you want to project it as a column value you can use this expression

CASE WHEN lefttable.column IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isNull